# Konsole: disable right-click menu

Tags: konsole

My trackpad does not have a middle button, so I have to click both buttons to simulate middle button. Often that fails and I get the context menu (which I have never ever had any use for in Konsole).

I would like to either disable the context menu or (even better) have the right-click be interpreted as a middle click.

Comment: I couldn't find it on my KDE. If it can be of any help, you can try 1) keyboard shortcuts (`Ctrl+Shift+C`, `Ctrl+Shift+V` to copy from/paste in terminal), or 2) configure your touchpad (from KDE configuration panel device, input devices, touchpad) to emulate middle button with several-finger taps (if available), or taps in corners of your touchpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that fixes your problem in `konsole`, but does affect not only the mouse use in `konsole`, but in general.

Using [`xmodmap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html), the mouse buttons can be reordered.

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 3 2"`

will make the right button act as a middle button, and the middle button act as a right button.

Now, your trackpad has a "middle button", but no "right button".
And I'm curious what you need to press to simulate the right button - confusing!

Comment: It does not really answer the question, and I did not think it would be an acceptable solution to me - as I use the right button some times. But I have now tried using it for a few days, and it actually works OK: To right-click I press both buttons - and in practice I rarely do that, whereas I middle-click all the time.